# Orthogonal trajectoroes of confocal ellipses

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, conic-sections

Trying to obtain an orthogonal trajectory set for constant $c$ and variable $a$. Employing standard symbols, the primes are w.r.t. $x,$

$$ \frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{a^2-c^2}=1;\; e= c/a;\; \to x^2+ \frac{y^2}{1-e^2}=\frac{c^2}{e^2} \tag 1$$

Differentiate and simplify

$$ x +\frac{yy'}{1-e^2}=0 \tag 2$$

Eliminating $(1-e^2)$ between 1) & 2)

$$ x^2 +\frac{y^2 x}{-yy'}=\frac{c^2}{1+yy'/x}\tag3 $$

To obtain ode for orthogonal trajectory replacing $ y$ by $-1/y'$

$$ x^2+ xyy' = \frac{xy'c^2}{xy'-y}\tag 4 $$

Simplifies to
$$\frac{1-y^{'2}}{y'}=\frac{x^2-y^2-c^2}{xy}= 2 P \text{ say . Then, quadratic solutions }\tag 5 $$

$$ y'= -P\pm \sqrt{1+P^2}\tag 6 $$

How to proceed further to obtain the known con-focal hyperbolas, and if correct, to identify the two hyperbola sets geometrically? Please help.

(I had done these a long time before but unfortunately don't seem to get it now once again. :(  may be missing a simple thing). Thanks in advance.